# Problems when oppening the same html file in different windows

Tags: javascript, window, conflict, qunit

I have already programmed the tetris game in html and javascript and I discover a very curious thing when I was testing it. First of all, I am going to explain what I do.

When a shape of the tetris game falls down to the bottom of the board, I add a reference to that shape in a variable named "grid". I test this opening a qunit in an explorer window and all goes fine. But when I open 2 different windows, opening the same QUnit in both of them, it seems that the 2 .html files have a conflict between them, because in one of them (the one which finishes first) all goes fine, but in the other, it seems that the variable "grid" is already filled.

My question is: is it possible? In an affirmative case. WHY?!

Comment: Are you using cookies or localStorage? Javascript variables should not be visible between windows, but cookies and localStorage are.

Comment: Does it happen if you open them without QUnit?

Comment: I use localstorage, but in this case it doesn't matter because the variable "grid" is an internal variable of one of the javascript functions.

Comment: When I open it without QUnit it doesn't happen. All goes fine... That's the point of the matter...!

Comment: Since the problem is specific to QUnit, you should have put that in the tags so the QUnit experts will notice it.

Comment: Is it a local variable declared with `var`, or a global variable?

Comment: It's a variable declared this way: this.grid;

Comment: Post your code if you want help with it.